# FX7500 Embedded Java Application Start/Stop

Tags: java, rfid, reader

We have deployed a Java application to the FX7500 RFID reader and can manually execute the program through a ssh session, but we are looking into how the application will auto-start when the reader boots.  It looks like the FX7500 SDK comes with some sample scripts to start and stop the application, but I don't see how those scripts get executed (other than through an ssh session).  I see the "Applications" page in the FX7500 web interface is used for uploading C and C++ packages, and that provides start/stop/auto-start options for those types of applications.

Is there anyway to setup a Java application on the FX7500 RFID reader so the application can be started and stopped from the web interface and start automatically when the reader is powered on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zebra SDK for embedded FX7500 development includes the tools to create debian packages for Java applications.  The end result is a .deb file that contains your application that can be installed on the reader and configured for auto-start.

Comment: Do you know how I can install the .deb file on my Zebra FX7500 reader? In the following path "Motorola-FX7500-Embedded-SDK\buildPackages\all_build", there is a file called "RFIDSample4App_1.0.0" with type as deb. But I am not sure how to install the same on reader and configure it. I read the "Creating an FX RFID Reader Embedded Application Installation Package
on Linux Host" topic provided in the pdf "fx series embedded sdk-pg-en" but I am not able to understand it. Please guide me

Comment: I don't have a FX7500 with me, but isn't there a web page on the reader that allows you to upload and install the .deb package that is created with the SDK? If I remember correctly the install will fail if the .deb package was not built correctly.  At that point the install files can be accessed through SSH and configured as needed.

Comment: Yes. I was able to import the deb file on the reader through Zebra web portal. Thanks